Global policies.json equivilent for Macos
I have successfully used a policies.json file in /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution (which I had to create), per the following:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson
How do I instruct Firefox to allow me to open file:/// URLs on a localhost-server http:// webpage?
I am using it to allow local file links from a private site.  My policy is:
{
  "policies": {
    "LocalFileLinks": ["http://example.org/"]
  }
}

Everything works as expected.
However on Macos, the policy is stored in the application folder, rather than on the system.  I would like to have it in a less volatile location.  The MDN page I linked to suggests (somewhat ambiguously) /etc/firefox/policies , but that apparently only applies to Linux as it did not work on my system.
Is there a location on my system which Firefox checks for policies on startup other than inside the app?
All of my searches only refer the the location within the app as I have used.
